# adding two column of a data where col1 contains date and col2 contains days

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which i have two columns date and days and i want to add date column with days and show the result in other column 
data frame-1
col date is in format of mm/dd/yyyy format

```
date        days
3/2/2019    8
3/5/2019    4
3/6/2019    4
3/21/2019   3
3/25/2019   7
```

and i want my output like this

```
date        days    new-date
3/2/2019    8       3/10/2019
3/5/2019    4       3/9/2019
3/6/2019    4       3/10/2019
3/21/2019   3       3/24/2019
3/25/2019   7       4/1/2019
```

i was trying this

```
as.Date("3/10/2019") +8
```

but i think it will work for a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to actual `Date` values and then add `Days`. You need to specify the actual format of `date` (read `?strptime`) while converting it to Date.

```
as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y") + df$days
#[1] "2019-03-10" "2019-03-09" "2019-03-10" "2019-03-24" "2019-04-01"
```

If you want the output back in same format, we can use `format`

```
df$new_date <- format(as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y") + df$days, "%m/%d/%Y")

df
#       date days   new_date
#1  3/2/2019    8 03/10/2019
#2  3/5/2019    4 03/09/2019
#3  3/6/2019    4 03/10/2019
#4 3/21/2019    3 03/24/2019
#5 3/25/2019    7 04/01/2019
```

---

If you get confused with different date format we can use `lubridate` to do

```
library(lubridate)
with(df, mdy(date) + days)
```